# Netflix Zuul cannot resolve configuration properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, pom.xml, netflix-zuul

So I'm trying to use Zuul as an API gateway and one of my requests takes a while. I am getting a socket timeout exception, but when I try to change things related to timeout in my application.yml my IDE tells me it cannot resolve the configuration properties

For example, this does not exist:

```
hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          strategy: THREAD
           thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 10000
```

I must be missing something in my pom.xml, but I don't know what. Here are the dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zuul</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-ribbon</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT:

This was simply an issue with the IDE not recognizing the config. It works as intended. The IDE used is intelliJ

Comment: Can you send cloud dependency in pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

change to this

```
hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 20000
```

Comment: So apparently what I did was not wrong at all, but the IDE could just not find the reference to the configuration. Silly me for relying on it! Thanks anyway though.